# Using broadcast receiver to invoke an application via SMS

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I need to invoke an application by sending an sms to the mobile.
For eg: sending "REC" as a sms to the mobile should invoke an application, 
Need to implement it with the help of broadcast receiver.
But i m beginner in android. It ll be helpful if somebody gives snippets for it

Comment: use the search function. this has been discussed thousand times